# Webpack freezes without finishing

Tags: webpack

I have a project using webpack, and it's suddenly started freezing when I make a code change. The strange thing is, simply changing the name of a `var` or removing characters from a `string` has started causing webpack to freeze.

I think it's down to either `elm-webpack-loader` or `terser` but I can't figure out how to debug webpack. I've looked around the webpack site, but can't find anything useful.

In case it helps here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  const devMode = options.mode !== 'production';

  return {
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            ecma: 5,
            compress: {
              pure_funcs: [
                "F2",
                "F3",
                "F4",
                "F5",
                "F6",
                "F7",
                "F8",
                "F9",
                "A2",
                "A3",
                "A4",
                "A5",
                "A6",
                "A7",
                "A8",
                "A9"
              ],
              pure_getters: true,
              keep_fargs: false,
              unsafe_comps: true,
              unsafe: true,
              passes: 2
            },
            mangle: true
          }
        }),
      ]
    },
    entry: {
      'app': glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js').concat(['./js/app.js'])
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js'),
      publicPath: '/js/'
    },
    devtool: devMode ? 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' : undefined,
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.elm$/,
          exclude: [/elm-stuff/, /node_modules/],
          use: {
            loader: 'elm-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              cwd: __dirname,
              debug: false, //options.mode === "development",
              optimize: options.mode === "production"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'static/', to: '../' }])
    ]
  }
};
```

I don't think I can provide enough information initially to solve this exact problem, so I guess I'm asking for pointers on how to debug webpack.

**Edit:** I think I may have narrowed it down to the `terser-webpack-plugin` namely `node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/worker.js:10`. The line `const result = minify(options);` does not complete.

I've added the following to `worker.js`:

```
var stdout = require("stdout-stream");
```

and changed:

```
const result = minify(options);
```

to

```
stdout.write("\nworker, minify : start\n")

const result = minify(options);

stdout.write("\nworker, minify : end\n")
```

along with the following to `minify.js`:

```
var stdout = require("stdout-stream");
```

and changed

```
const minify = options => {
  const {
    file,
    input,
    inputSourceMap,
    minify: minifyFn
  } = options;
```

to

```
const minify = options => {
  stdout.write("minify")
  const {
    file,
    input,
    inputSourceMap,
    minify: minifyFn
  } = options;
```

So if all goes well, I should see the following output:

```
worker, minify : start
minify
worker, minify : end
```

But the only output I see is:

`worker, minify : start`

and then the process hangs without ever completing.

I thought I would at least see

```
worker, minify : start
minify
```

I think I'm truly at a dead end now, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** package.json

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "description": " ",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "postinstall": "elm-tooling install",
    "test": "cd elm && elm-test-rs"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "^7.5.0",
    "elm-webpack-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "elm-tooling": "^1.0.2",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: please post your package.json

Comment: I've edited my question to include package.json